# to input data to structure member is a pointer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct test
{
    int x;
    int *y;
};

main()
{
    struct test *a;
    a = malloc(sizeof(struct test));

    a->x =10;
    a->y = 12;
    printf("%d %d", a->x,a->y);
}
```

I get the o/p but there is a warning

```
 warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

and

```
 warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’
```

how to input a value to *y in struct test

Comment: Doug's answer below is 100% correct. However, I think what you really need is to read up on pointers, I don't think specifically solving this scenario will help you. There's excellent tutorials you can google.

Answer (score 6):

To access, you need to **dereference** the pointer returned by the expression a->y to maniputlate the pointed at value. To do this, use the unary * operator:

You also need to allocate memory for y to make sure it points at something:

```
a->y = malloc(sizeof(int));
...
*(a->y) = 12;
...
printf("%d %d", a->x,*(a->y));
```

And be sure to free malloc'd data in the reverse order it was  malloc'd

```
free(a->y);
free(a);
```